# Imported JQuery Code Not Affecting React Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm using an old-school payment portal in my React app which requires that their JQuery script is imported to properly render an `iFrame` widget.

I went into my `index.js` file in `public` folder and added the script into the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://vendorUrl.com/popup.js"></script>
```

Among other things, the referenced script ensures that the `iFrame` is hidden at launch until a button is clicked:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("SpecificIFrame");

    ...
    iframe.style.opacity = 0;
    iframe.style.transition = 'opacity .5s ease-in-out';

    jQuery(".show-popup").on("click",
        function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            openPopup();
        });
});

function openPopup() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("SpecificIFrame");
    iframe.style.opacity = 1;
    iframe.style.width = '100%';
    iframe.style.height = '100%';
    ...
}
```

So, when in my functional component I create the `iFrame`, I'm surprised to see that it's visible and ignores all the jQuery code in the external script.

```
import $ from "jquery";

export default function MyComponent() {
    return(
        <>
            <iframe 
                id='SpecificIFrame' 
                src='https://myUrl.com/...'>
            </iframe>
            <button className='show-popup'>Pay via Platform</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Why is the script being ignored? What can I do to fix this please?

Comment: What errors do you get in your console?

Comment: I don't get any. It's just that the jQuery code doesn't do anything, and hence the iFrame is not hidden when loaded.